# removeAllActions sprite kit moving background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I've created this SKSpriteNode which is the moving background in the background. What i would like to is being able to stop all actions which i've done by

```
[self removeAllAction]
```

Which works, but not on the moving background why? and how can i obtain this

```
    SKTexture* groundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"layer-1"];
    groundTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;


    SKAction* moveGroundSprite = [SKAction moveByX:-groundTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0.02 * groundTexture.size.width*2];
    SKAction* resetGroundSprite = [SKAction moveByX:groundTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0];
    moveGroundSpritesForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[moveGroundSprite, resetGroundSprite]]];

    for( int i = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width; ++i ) {
        // Create the sprite
        sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:groundTexture];
        [sprite setScale:1.0];
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(i * sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height / 2);
        [sprite runAction:moveGroundSpritesForever withKey:@"bg"];
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
```

Comment: You should call [removeAllAction] on `sprite`, not on `self`

Comment: i've tried both [self removeAllActions] and [sprite removeAllActions]

Comment: Paulw11 is right. The command [sprite removeAllActions] should stop any and all actions attached to your sprite. Are you perhaps restarting the the action at some point in your code that you are not aware of?

Comment: You can also try removing the action using removeAction:withKey:. This seems to work well with repeatForever actions.